# What is the topological dimension of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$? it is a separable topological space?

Tags: general-topology, dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, dimension-theory-analysis

Initially, consider $\mathbb{R}$ endowed with a discrete topology, and discrete metric $\delta(x,y)=0 $ if $x=y$ and $\delta(x,y)=1 $ if $x\neq y$.

Next, we endowing $~~\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}=\prod_{-\infty}^{+\infty} \mathbb{R}~~$ with the metric 
$$d(x,y)=\sum_{i=-\infty}^{+\infty}\frac{\delta(x_i,y_i)}{2^{|i|}},$$
where $x=(x_i),~  y=(y_i)\in \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$.

What is the topological dimension of  $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$?

Is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$ a discrete topological space?

Is $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{Z}$ a separable topological space?

Please help me! Thanks.

Comment: What have you tried? Which part are you struggling with so that we can better work out what kind of answer would work best for you.

Answer (score 0):

It is metric, but not separable (even one factor is not) and certainly not discrete (just like the Cantor set $\{0,1\}^\mathbb{Z}$ is not: basic open sets are never singletons). It is zero-dimensional as a countable product of zero-dimensional spaces.

Comment: is 0, in not and yes.

Comment: $0$, no,  no @AlexC.